# Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I've searched throughout many forums and there's not a single definitive solution for this issue. I keep getting this error despite actually putting a semi-colon in every possible position that I could find. Can someone please help me to identify where the issue is?

Code:

```
str = "Insert into tblAppointments([Day]) values (?) FROM tblAppointments WHERE TimeID ='" & redbutton & "'"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Day", CType(day, String)))
```

Comment: What is `redbutton` and how is it populated?  This could be vulnerable to a sql injection attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is wrong and malformed. There shouldn't be any `FROM` clause unless you are using `insert into .. select from` construct. It should just be

```
insert into tblAppointments([Day]) values (?)
```